# RedGate - Computed Column Dependent on Function Fails in Migration

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, redgate

We've added a new computed column to a SQL Server database table.  The new computed column is dependent on a new function.

When we attempt to deploy the branch, migrations reports the error shown below.

```
Error: Synchronization of 'Scripts.RedGate' and 'SomeServer.SomeDb' failed:
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate
"dbo.IsACredit", or the name is ambiguous. Error executing the following SQL:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable] ADD [IsCredit] AS ([dbo].[IsACredit]([ID]))
```

How can we successfully deploy these needed database changes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you selected to include dependencies?

Comment: No we have not.  Can you advise how to accomplish this?

Comment: Presumably using Regate sqlcompare to generate your scripts? https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-compare/sql-compare-project-options

Comment: Thank you!  We will look at this.  When we commit our database updates, we see no checkbox in RedGate Source Control.